# Deleting browsing history at work

Tags: history, browsing

Hi I stupidly spent too much time recently browsing internet at work.  I'm worried this could lead to a disciplinary and wondered if there was any way of really deleting this from the server.  I used google chrome.  Would really appreciate any help.  Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this website is the place for these type of questions, however I could guess with reasonable confidence that the answer is no but this is subject as to whether they actually store logs of user activity or not.

Comment: What you can do is delete your browsing history and delete all the media you may have downloaded on your PC. For cleaning I use a small tool, DriveTidy, but you can choose any one of them. Just search on Google. It's very unlikely that they are close monitoring your PC activity. The IT departments are more concerned about security threats, than users spending time on facebook. :)

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on whether your work IT department log Internet activity on the company network...

If they do then almost certainly an employee won't have access to these and will certainly not be able to delete them to "cover their tracks".

Talking to your IT department will give you your answer...

The simple answer is: if you don't know then don't do it.